# How Join hibernate Value objects using HQL query?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Hi i'm New to write HQL Query please help me.....
 my Hibernate have three ValueObjects ie.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class UserVO {

    @Id
    @Column(name="S_ID")
    private String s_id;

    @Column(name="FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstName;
    private String email;
}
```

CourseVO class

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="course")
public class CourseVO
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="S_ID")
    public String s_id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    public String name;
}
```

Skillset VO

```
@Entity
@Table(name="skillset")
public class SkillsetVO 
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="S_ID")
    public String s_id;

    @Column(name="COURSE_ID")//Foreign Key "USER"
    public String course_id;

    @Column(name="USER_ID")//Foreign key "COURSE"
    public String user_id;

    @Column(name="TEACH_EXP")
    public String teach_Exp;
}
```

Now How to get Values of FirstName,NAME,TEACH_EXP values using EMAIL of USER table using `HQL` query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `join` syntax in `HQL` you must work out your `mapping` accordingly as joins are enabled by mapping.

```
@Entity class A { @OneToMany private List<B> bs; }
@Entity class B { @Basic int n; }
```

Enables

```
select b from A a inner join a.b where a = :id
```

But with your mapping this is not possible. Also bear in mind that in terms of efficiency most of the `RDBMs` will perform an inner join on a `where a.id = b.id`.

```
select u.firstName, c.name, s.teach_Exp
from UserVO u, CourseVO c, SkillsetVO s 
where
    u.s_id = s.user_id 
    and c.s_id = s.course_id 
    and u.email = :email
```

But I think that you must review you association. Since looks to me that `SkillsetVO.user_id` should be `SkillsetVO.User` (an association to a `UserVO` entity and same for `CourseVO`).

Comment: Thankyou..Correct, i'm using one to many association CourseVO and UserVO class.but your query have no join why HQL not support joins?or using 'and' operator is easy and correct way?